# How to configure ADE7953 metering IC

Tags: uart

I am working with ADE7953 metering IC and I use the uart serial communication in raspberry pi to communicate with the IC and i have wiring pi installed in it.Can anyone help me regarding how to configure the IC.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the datasheets and look for the MODE register configuration. Also take care for the active energy line cycle accumulation mode registers to set before you take IRMS or VRMS any of the ENERGY register

Answer (score 1):

The ADE7953 contains a detection system that automatically 
detects which of the three communication interfaces is being 
used.

- The CS pin (Pin 28) is used to determine whether the 
  communication method is SPI. The pin must be low 
  during the SPI communication for this interface method. 
  The CS pin is active low and will automatically lock onto 
  SPI communication as a result.
- The SCLK pin (Pin 25) is used to determine whether the 
  communication method is I2
  C or UART. If this pin is held 
  high, the communication interface is set to I
  2
  C; if it is held 
  low, the communication interface is set to UART.

Now, for UART should be configured in hardware as  pin28 should be high, pin25 should be low, pin 27 Rx and pin 26 Tx